# Getting userid from apache webserver after pubcookie authentication

Tags: java, apache, cookies, jboss, session-cookies

I am working on an application which will use pubcookie authentication. My application runs on JBoss server and is front ended by Apache webserver which has the pubcookie setup. I have been able to setup the pubcookie module and the user authentication happens fine whenever a user tries to access a resource from my application. However, I am unable to pass the logged in user's id from apache webserver to my application running on JBoss server. I need this information in my application in order for my application to lookup its datastore and determine the users permissions. How does this information flow happen?

Comment: Hi Guys, re-checking if someone could help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pubcookie puts the logged-in user into the REMOTE_USER environment variable.